# "Error Segmentation fault (core dumped)" while working with Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have this code and it works perfectly fine **except when my input is the number "2"**.

I don't know why, the code seems ok...
Is there something wrong?

```
void initValue(int *a, int dim, int value, int i);
int findValue(int *a, int dim, int value, int i);

main(){
    int i, value, dim = 5;
    int a[dim];

    initValue(a, dim, value, i);

    printf("\nYour values are: ");
    for(i = 0; i < dim; i++) printf("%d ", a[i]);
    printf("\n\n");
}

void initValue(int *a, int dim, int value, int i){
    printf("Insert your values:\n");

    for(i = 0; i < dim; i++){
        scanf("%d", &value);
        if(findValue(a, dim, value, i) == 1){
            printf("This value already exist, please insert a new one.\n");
            i--;
        }
        else a[i] = value;
    }
}

int findValue(int *a, int dim, int value, int i){
    int j, result = 0;
    for(j = 0; j < i || a[j] != value; j++) if(a[j] == value) result = 1;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`). Read about [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: I see no point in passing the variables from `main()` except for `int *a` and `int dim`, why are you doing that? Also, what is your input?

Comment: @iharob my prof gave me this exercise :(

Comment: @ArtjomB. ok, sorry xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in your code is a logic error in this line:

```
for(j = 0; j < i || a[j] != value; j++) if(a[j] == value) result = 1;
```

Say you have `dim=5` and `i=2` and `value=10`, which is not there is `a`. The loop will not stop at `j=2` because `a[j] != value` is true. After that you are entering undefined behavior territory.

That line needs to be changed to:

```
for(j = 0; j < i ; j++) if(a[j] == value) return 1;
```

The function can now be simplified to:

```
int findValue(int *a, int dim, int value, int i){
   int j = 0;
   for(j = 0; j < i ; j++)
   {
      if(a[j] == value)
      {
         result = 1;
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to check that `scanf()` did succeed, something like

   ```
   if (scanf("%d", &value) != 1)
       maybeRemoveAllWhitespacesAndScanfAgain_MaybeReturnWithAnError();
   ```
2. You decrement `i` and never check if `i < 0`

   ```
   for(i = 0; (i < dim) && (i >= 0) ; i++){
   ```
3. `initValue()` could be defined as

   ```
   void initValue(int *a, int dim)
   {
       int value;
       int i;
       .
       .
       .
   }
   ```

there is no point in passing the variables from `main()`.

One more thing, if you initialize `value` before `scanf()` you can prevent trying to access it while uninitialized.